# HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#

I am trying to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem as here

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((x) =>
            {
                while (true)
                {

                }
            });
```

but i got `System.InvalidOperationException : operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

Just create empty console project with .net Framework 4.7.2 and you should see this

Comment: Provide more info.

Comment: See [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8): This API cannot be called outside of an ASP.NET-managed AppDomain.